# Hibernate : JDBC connection established but no statements executed

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jar

I've made a DAO library using spring boot and hibernate. All unit tests on DAO methods are running perfectly.
But when I use this jar in another spring boot project, the JDBC connection with the datasource is established but statements are neither prepared nor executed. 
The DAO bean is correctly injected, session and transaction opens. 
I have no other errors or exceptions.

Hibernate statistics logs this :

```
2017-07-18 14:57:31.440  INFO 13736 --- [           main] i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener : Session Metrics {
75050 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
0 nanoseconds spent preparing 0 JDBC statements;
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
52279 nanoseconds spent executing 1 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
```

Any ideas?

EDIT : Some of my code

The DAO implementation :

```
@Repository
public class CompagnieDaoImpl implements CompagnieDao {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CompagnieDaoImpl.class);

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Compagnie> get() {
        Session session = null;
        Transaction transaction = null;
        List<Compagnie> compagnies = null;
        try {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            compagnies = session.createCriteria(Compagnie.class).list();
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (Throwable ex){
            logger.error("CompagnieDaoImpl.get exception : " + ex.getMessage());
            if (session != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            if (session != null) {
                session.close(); 
            }
        }       
        return compagnies;
    }
```

DAO interface :

```
public interface CompagnieDao {
    public List<Compagnie> get();
}
```

Custom properties :

```
{"properties": [
  {
    "name": "clipperton.datasource.password",
    "type": "java.lang.String",
    "description": "A description for 'clipperton.datasource.password'"
  },
  {
    "name": "clipperton.datasource.url",
    "type": "java.lang.String",
    "description": "A description for 'clipperton.datasource.url'"
  },
  {
    "name": "clipperton.datasource.driver-class-name",
    "type": "java.lang.String",
    "description": "A description for 'clipperton.datasource.driver-class-name'"
  },
  {
    "name": "clipperton.datasource.username",
    "type": "java.lang.String",
    "description": "A description for 'clipperton.datasource.username'"
  }
]}
```

Now, in the project using this library :

Application properties :

```
#Datasource
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
clipperton.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/clipperton
clipperton.datasource.username=*****
clipperton.datasource.password=*****
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
clipperton.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

#Hibernate
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.generate_statistics=true

#debug
debug=true
```

The main class

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"fr.example.spring.clipperton.clippertondao"})
@Import({DataSourceConfiguration.class, SessionFactoryConfiguration.class})
public class ClippertonStandaloneApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ClippertonStandaloneApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And finally, the test class :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes=ClippertonStandaloneApplication.class)
public class ClippertonStandaloneApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    CompagnieDao compagnieDao;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
         assertNotNull(compagnieDao);
    }

    @Test
    public void readCompanies() {
        List<Compagnie> compagnies = compagnieDao.get();
        assertEquals(1, compagnies.size());
    }
```

Datasource

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class DataSourceConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="clipperton.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
}
```

SessionFactory

```
   @Configuration
    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    public class SessionFactoryConfiguration {
        @Bean
        public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
            HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean fact = new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
            fact.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
            return fact;
        }
    }
```

Comment: My crystal ball is out of order. Can you at least include *some* of your code to show what you have done.

Comment: Code added, sir.

Comment: Can you also add the classes SessionFactoryConfiguration and DataSourceConfiguration?

Comment: Done, note that those beans are injected without raising any exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The @EntityScan annotation was lacking for the spring boot application main class.

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"fr.example.spring.clipperton.clippertondao"})
@EntityScan(basePackages = "fr.example.spring.clipperton.clippertondao.domain")
@Import({DataSourceConfiguration.class, SessionFactoryConfiguration.class})
public class ClippertonStandaloneApplication { ... }
```